# How to echo (array with $i) blade in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to append array with $i in blade?

`model`:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'positive1', 'positive2', 'positive3', 'positive4', 'positive5'
];
```

`blade`: // Befor this loop is: `@foreach($commentHotel as $value)`

```
@for($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
  @if($value -> positive[$i] != '')
    <li class="clearfix"><i class="icon icon-arrow-top"></i> <span>{{ $value -> positive[$i] }}</span></li>
  @endif
@endfor
```

This code is error: `$value -> positive[$i]`.
I would like to print:

```
$value -> positive1
$value -> positive2
$value -> positive3
$value -> positive4
$value -> positive5
```

How do I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `$value -> positive[$i]`, write
`$value->getAttribute("positive$i")`

Comment: This example uses an Eloquent method, so it's handy to know. However, when dealing with objects and variable names, you can also do something like `$value->{"positive{$i}"}`

Answer (score 2):

nXu's example is handy because it shows you how to access a model attribute when using Eloquent. However, there is a way to access dynamic method and property names in PHP.

```
// Access a dynamic property name
$value->{"positive{$i}"}

// Call a dynamic method name
$value->{$functionName}()
```

Using the `{}` braces allows you to interpolate a dynamic value.